# 32bit integer scaling with no overrun

Tags: c++, c, binary, integer, bit-manipulation

Hi I have a following values:

```
uint32_t value = 1230000;
uint32_t max_value = 1234567;
```

Now, I would like to perform scaling:

```
uint32_t scaled = value * 1000000 / max_value;
```

The problem is if I use 32bit integer it will overrun for such big numbers.
On the other hand I cannot use 64bit. Any idea how to properly implement mentioned scaling?

**EDIT**

Just to mention, I am working on STM32 - a 32-bit micro-controller, where performing 64-bit multiplication and division is extremely costly. Therefore I would like to avoid them.

Comment: What cpu architecture and compiler is this with?

Comment: Please explain the statement: *"On the other hand I cannot use 64bit"*. Why not?

Comment: I am working on STM32 microcontroller, and 64bit divide is as complex as here: http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.22/lib/div64.c. I would like to avoid that

Comment: Is there any way to generate the UMULL instruction? Scaling like this could be done (approximately at least) with that and then using the upper half of the result

Comment: A few questions: How accurate should your scaling be? Are the numbers 1000000 and 1234567 fixed, or can those be changed?

Comment: Can you do a struct composed of two uint32_t? If so you can recreate operations (+, -, /, %, *) yourself, but it will be a bit long and quite complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by seeing scale as a base-1000 number: `value = value_high*1000 + value_low`. Calculate `value_high`'s and `value_low`'s contribution to scaled separately, storing the intermediate values as a fraction: `scaled = scaled_int + scaled_remainder/max_value`

```
uint32_t value_low = value%1000;
uint32_t value_high = value/1000;
uint32_t scaled_int, scaled_remainder;

uint32_t low = value_low * 1000000;
scaled_int = low / max_value;
scaled_remainder = low % max_value;

scaled_int += value_high * 810;  // pre-calculated 1000*1000000 / max_value
scaled_remainder += value_high * 730;  // pre-calculated 1000*1000000 % max_value
scaled_int += scaled_remainder / max_value;
scaled_remainder = scaled_remainder % max_value;
```

Also, you don't have to use base 1000, base 1024 might be a bit faster. As long as the 4th and 8th line don't overflow at their maximum value, it should work.

Comment: I like this solution very very much. But is it correct? I found my result is exactly 1000x higher than expected, but very accurate!

Comment: How should I correct this to have the expected result? I know I can divide it by 1000 and add the rest to remainder, but I guess there is much optimal way, isn't it? :)

Comment: It was the calculation of value_high, chqrlie's suggestion would have needed another `/1000`, and I didn't catch it.

Answer (score 2):

you can declare `scaled` as `unsigned long long` type  like below & then do explicit typecast accordingly.

```
unsigned long long scaled = (unsigned long long)value * 1000000 / max_value; /* make either operand of unsigned long long type explicitly */
printf("%llu\n",scaled);
```

Comment: I cannot use 64bit as it is to costly on 32bit machine

Answer (score 1):

if your translater can support 64bit,then

```
uint32_t scaled =(uint32_t)((uint64_t)value * 1000000 / max_value);
```

if support float,then

```
uint32_t scaled =(uint32_t)(value *1.0 / max_value* 1000000);
```

There will be a little loss of precision.

Comment: I cannot use 64bit as it is to costly on 32bit machine. The same problem is with real numbers (float and double)

Comment: most of the F2+ STM uCs have hardware float (and some double)|FPU. So those operations are not costly at all.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way of scaling is using the 2 power scale factors.

Even you have two numbers scaled using different scale factors - the arithmetic is trivial.

example:

```
uint32_t scaledDiv(uint32_t a, uint32_t b, uint32_t *sclef)
{
    *sclef = __builtin_clz(a);
    a <<= *sclef;
    return a/b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is of form: `value/max_1 = x/1000000`.

Without solving this in closed form, the closest `x` can be calculated iteratively using bisection.

```
 uint32_t step=max_value>>1;
 uint32_t v=0, x=0, step2=1000000/2 << 12;
 // step2 has been scaled to add extra precision
 while(step) {
    if (value > v+step) { v+=step; x+=step2; }
    step>>=1; step2>>=1;
 }
 x=(x+2048)>>12; // scale down and round
```

The result will finish in 32 iterations.